# How to remove index extension for html using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, cpanel

how to remove html index using htacces?

when people type main url, it automatic go to the page without the page  extention name.

Example
`www.abc.com/home.html` to become `www.abc.com only`

i try search for the file but only hide the extension only.
how to hide the pagename also?

Comment: Rename the file to `index.html`, then you get this “gratis” with any web server in default configuration.

Comment: what a simple answer..please put this as answer so i can rate and remeber this answer again later as reference.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when people type main url, it automatic go to the page without the page extention name.
>
> Example `www.abc.com/home.html` to become `www.abc.com` only

Rename the file to `index.html`, then you get this “gratis” with most web servers in default configuration; they will automatically look for a file named `index.htm(l)` or `index.php`, when a request for a directory is made.